# ask <invocation name> utterance does not work on device, but works in simulator

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an alexa skill  It's been working fine for around a year.  It just recently stopped working when using the ask "skillname" to "intent".  It works perfectly when i use the simulator but when I try this pattern from my devices, it simply replies "I'm not sure what went wrong".  I have alot of logging in my lambda function and it never logs one line of code executed.  So it seems it is never making it to the lambda function.  If i ask my devices to open "skillname", and then say the intent utterances, it works perfectly on a device.  I'm at a loss as to why this stopped working within the last week?

Alexa simulator, different variations of utterances, etc.

Every intent starts with: 
    console.log("In Handler. handlerInput: " + JSON.stringify(handlerInput, null, 2));

Comment: Posting the relevant code makes helping you easier for us.

Comment: Could you share your code, would be easier to help you :D, you can also try with an empty intent to see if it's working, to be sure that it's coming from your code